# Second to last item in django-simple-history

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am seeking to make a recent history box displaying the last 3 changes to a model. I know that one can call `model.history.most_recent()`, but what I need are the 2nd and 3rd most recent items as well. How would one gain access to these models? Further, how would one loop through this new model instance to see changes that have occured?

If there is a better app to be using, please inform me as well.

Documentation: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#locating-past-model-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As history all looks like a list:

```
model.history.all()[:-3]
```

Should get the last 3 but it looks like it uses an iterator that doesn't support negative indexes.  You could possibly use something like:

```
last3 = []
for h in model.history.all:
   if len(last3) > 2:
       del last3[0]
   last3.append[h]
```

but you might wish to seect by date to limit changes to recent.

Comment: This returns the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    "Negative indexing is not supported."
AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.`

Comment: What does `model.history.all()` give?

Comment: `<HistoricalModel: Model 1 as of 2013-09-29 02:00:04.843062+00:00>, <HistoricalModel: Model 1 as of 2013-09-29 01:59:32.261697+00:00>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']`